# How to run two instances of Apache ActiveMQ in one system?

Tags: apache, activemq-classic

I am using apache-activemq-5.11.1 which is the stable version runs on JDK 7 (Major version 51.0), I am using JDK 7 Update 80. I had error if I run the same on JDK 6.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/ac
>   tivemq/console/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Coming to my problem I need to have two running instances of ActiveMQ in my system. I had followed the following steps to create two instance.

```
C:\>cd \apache-activemq-5.11.1
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1>.\bin\activemq create instance1
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1>.\bin\activemq create instance2
```

I had changed to different set of port numbers for *instance2* as below,

```
<!--EDITED: apache-activemq-5.11.1\instance2\conf\activemq.xml-->

    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61716?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5772?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61713?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1983?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61714?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Now I am starting instance1 & instance2 as follows.....

```
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\instance1\bin>instance1 start
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\instance1\bin>instance2 start
```

Among these the second instance which I am trying to start gives the following kahadb lock problem.....

```
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@7209d9af: startup date [Thu May 07 16:16:23 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\data\kahadb]
 INFO | Database C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\data\kahadb\lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: File 'C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\data\kahadb\lock' could not be locked.
```

Please give a solution for this db lock issue.

Answer (score 5):

Make a replica of your ActiveMQ like `apache-activemq-x.xx.x` to `apache-activemq-x.xx.x_2`

Change the ports of `apache-activemq-x.xx.x_2\conf\activemq.xml`. Make sure the port numbers that you are changing are not in clash.

```
<!--EDIT: apache-activemq-5.11.1_2\conf\activemq.xml-->
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61716?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5772?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61713?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1983?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61714?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

And along with port changes we have to correct jetty.xml http management console port as well.

```
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
         <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <property name="port" value="8162"/>
</bean>
```

In this way you can run two services of ActiveMQ in one system.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same in ActiveMQ-5.14.1. I did all the changes in configuration but i am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized" error for the instance which is started later. What am I missing here?

Comment: If ports not in conflict, problem maybe something different as you stated `java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized`, here this question discusses different topic, you could post your question with relevant information as a another topic. However so, let me look there at my oversight if I can. How so, you can recheck your ports between instances. In my case I left off only `jetty`.

Comment: I am really sorry, it was because of ports only. i looked into the logs very carefully and found the problem. tysm

Comment: Ok, still you can post as question and answer yourself, on what port conflict this particular error arisen, say `openwire` or so, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation, it almost worked for me. I was seeing an additional error _The service already exists_ when running the `bin\win64\InstallService.bat` script. The fix was to change the name of the service in `bin\win64\wrapper.conf` (The same would apply for `win32` installation as well). Look for `wrapper.ntservice.name=ActiveMQ` and `wrapper.ntservice.displayname=ActiveMQ`, and change the values to something else.

Comment: This works but it's an overkill. check @manuel-jordan 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576384/3367392).

Comment: @aboudirawas it actually depends on the scenario, as in my case instance solution does not work as i need separate copies of activemq as separate distributions.

Answer (score 5):

Running more instances created for ActiveMQ gives the Fail Over option.

In this way when one instance goes down for some reason. The other instance coming up automatically, since the first instance which locks the KahaDB is been released.

For this ports are not to be changed,- as we're configuring instances for Fail Over Mode.

```
C:\>cd \apache-activemq-5.11.1
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1>.\bin\activemq create instance1
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1>.\bin\activemq create instance2
```

Please start instances without changing any of the configuration. So when instance1 goes down for any reason, instance2 coming up.

```
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\instance1\bin>instance1 start
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\instance2\bin>instance2 start
```

I hope this must be the purpose of creating multiple instances under ActiveMQ. And more than this some more tweaky config. also available for Kahadb.

Comment: Windows is concerned I was able to do this in dos-prompt. But failed to run parallel instances in Redhat Linux, hope should be the same in other UNIX based machines. I had tried for `apache-activemq-5.11.1`.

Answer (score 4):

I did do the following instructions from:

- [Running Multiple ActiveMQ Instances on One Machine (Dzone)](https://dzone.com/articles/running-multiple-activemq)

It works fine for `Mac` (Not tested in `Linux`)

**Note**: the instances must be started through `instanceNumber start` (the *console* argument/parameter is not valid anymore).

I had the same problem about the `kahadb` locking **only** for `Windows`, it for `ActiveMQ` *5.13.3* and *5.14.5* versions

The same author from DZone wrote *practically* the same post in his blog

- [Running multiple ActiveMQ instances on one machine (Blog)](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/running-multiple-activemq-instances-on-one-machine/)

**But** there exists an important update.

You must open each `instanceNumber.bat` file for each instance from each `bin` directory and add these two lines:

```
set ACTIVEMQ_CONF="ACTIVEMQ_HOME/instanceNumber/conf"
set ACTIVEMQ_DATA="ACTIVEMQ_HOME/instanceNumber/data"
```

Where `ACTIVEMQ_HOME` represents the path location of your `ActiveMQ` and `instanceNumber` is the instance being edited such as: `instanceA` and `instanceB`

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is you have changed the port numbers correctly but both the instances that you created use a same Database(in this case file system KahaDB) to store their messages,

So when one instance is up and running, it holds the lock for that database and other instance of activeMQ will be waiting to gain a lock of this DB.
Essentially this is becoming a master slave configuration .

look at this line in activeMQ.xml

```
<persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

this will be pointing so same location for both instances.

what my solution is to copy entire folder `apache-activemq-x.xx.x` in different location change the port numbers for second instance and run them differently
by this you will have 2 instances of activeMQ running on same machine

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: I made replica of activemq across drives. That time both instance looks for C: drive kahadb. And if I create it under the same drive like `apache-activemq-x.xx.x` `apache-activemq-x.xx.x_2`, however the way it is _2 is not starting the instance only. Here I did not forget to change port numbers on both scenario.

Comment: In windows however we are able to create multiple instance for activemq, due to file lock, we are not able to run created instances. Apache didn't consider running multiple instances in Windows environment in the same system. Apache talks about Master-Slave mode of ActiveMQ when it run across systems and shared kahadb on NFS. I feel Apache should consider creating separate kahadb for each instances which are all created under ActiveMQ framework.

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam any error logs or something we can have a look at?
regarding ur first comment , why dont you give a different directory for kahadb to both the activeMQ instance something like
`<kahaDB directory="C:/instance1/kahadb"/>` and for other instance `<kahaDB directory="C:/instance2/kahadb"/>` can you try this maybe this works

Comment: It wasn't the way as I told. If we make a replica like  `apache-activemq-x.xx.x_2' '~\conf\activemq.xml` takes only relative path for variable `${activemq.data}`. And along with port changes we have to correct jetty.xml http management console port as well. So then it works the way as you say. `<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
             <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <property name="port" value="816_"/>
    </bean>`

Comment: yes! I missed the point about jetty, nice that you pointed it out,
so does it now work correctly? do you face anymore issues?

Comment: add an answer yourself of what you did to get rid of your problem,
it might help others looking for same problem

Answer (score -1):

Although because of `KahaDB` restriction load balancing/fault tolerant configuration is restricted. We can use following kind of connection URL to utilize ActiveMQ load....

```
failover://(tcp://192.nnn.nn.nn:61616,tcp://192.nnn.nn.nn:61616)?randomize=false
```

`randomize=true` will made message shuffles between two AciveMQ in active mode, rather not by just fail-over of ActiveMQ......

Complete reference for this can be found under the following Apache Site link....

http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

But Still high availability (i.e, cluster) configuration make things stable for your App although Apache must advance ActiveMQ High Availability, hence things can work smoother.

The present Apache ActiveMQ High Availability configuration available in the following link.

http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html

Although `KahaDB` has file lock restriction, following tweaking/alternates ways of configuration can be done...

1)Shared File System Master Slave,- A shared file system such as a SAN
http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html

2)JDBC Master Slave,- A Shared database
http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html

3)Replicated LevelDB Store,- ZooKeeper Server
http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html

Over & above by having JCA connectors,- AS like JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere, Geronimo, Glassfish,- ActimeMQ patching as a kind of Resource Adapter can be done. And with Apache Camel (karaf), JBoss Fuse ESB kind of products HA & clustering of ActiveMQ can be done.